Fetch zip file from remote host to local takes forever
I have this task in an Ansible playbook:
- name: Copy volumes.zip to local
  fetch: 
    src: "/tmp/volumes.zip"
    dest: "/home/user/volumes/"
    flat: true

It never ends. volumes.zip size is about 500MB. After debugging, I can see connection is done ok. In fact, I have some previous tasks in the same playbook (for generating that volumes.zip file) and they work fine.
What is happening? Is there any alternative to fetch module?

ansible.posix.synchronize module

Does this answer your question? How to fetch large files from Managed Node in Ansible?

500Mb file is too big for fetch module. You can either use synchronize module or simple bash commands like rsync or scp.
Example with synchronize
- name: Copy volumes.zip to local
   mode: pull
   synchronize:
   src: rsync://host/tmp/volumes.zip
   dest: /home/user/volumes/

Example with scp
- name: Copy volumes.zip to local
  shell: ' scp remote_server:/home/user/volumes/volumes.zip /tmp/volumes.zip '
  delegate_to: localhost

